# PHP Conditional Working With Else Value Incorrectly

Tags: php, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I am writing a conditional in PHP to check if certain user credentials have been used, and am using an `if....elseif....else` conditional method to do it. In each statement, I am defining the value of a variable if that statement is true. No matter what, the `else` value is always being used.

Also, if you want brownie points, would this be easier to do with a `switch` statement?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = strong_crypt($_POST['password'] . $username );
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $allEmails = $row['email'];
    $allUnames = $row['uname'];
}

if($allEmails === $email)
{
    $message = "That email already exists. You can only have one account per email address.";
}
elseif($allUnames === $username)
{
    $message = "That username has already been taken. Please choose a different one.";
}
elseif($username === null || $email === null || $password === null || $name === null) 
{
    $message = "Please fill out all fields to register";
}
else
{
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO login (name, uname, pword, email, lat, lon, it) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$lat', '$lon', '$it')");
    $message = "goodtogo";
}
```

Comment: How many rows your SELECT statement which is fetched should return? P.S.: In your if's you are not comparing types, aren't you? Maybe `==` only?

Comment: The === Operator checks if they both have same value & type. Have you tried == ?

Comment: consider that $allEmails and $uNames are the last fetched users's email and name. So actually the if-else if conditions are checking $username, $email etc with the last user only not with every row of data.

Comment: Its returning more than one value. And I just realized that I need to loop through all the values

Comment: please check the data before the if statements begin with `printf("allEmails: %s allUnames: %s username: %s email: %s $password: %s name: %s", $allEmails, $allUnames, $username, $email, $password, $name);`. What do you get?

Comment: Yes I tried `==` before and it made no difference. @MuhammedHedayet is right. I forgot that I need to put all the results in an array and loop through the array to compare.

Comment: please make that `else if` `elseif` :) . I could not edit becuase it were less then 6 chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue here is that you're doing the checks outside of the while loop, so that the check will always be done against the values from the LAST row of your query. Perhaps this code is more what you were aiming for?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = strong_crypt($_POST['password'] . $username );
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = '';

if($username === null || $email === null || $password === null || $name === null) 
{
    $message = "Please fill out all fields to register";
}
else
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $allEmails = $row['email'];
        $allUnames = $row['uname'];

        if($allEmails === $email)
        {
            $message = "That email already exists. You can only have one account per email address.";
            break;
        }
        else if($allUnames === $username)
        {
            $message = "That username has already been taken. Please choose a different one.";
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (!$message)
{
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO login (name, uname, pword, email, lat, lon, it) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$lat', '$lon', '$it')");
    $message = "goodtogo";
}
```

Comment: Should be easier to "SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE email = '$email' OR name = '$name'". Then check if one or more results

Comment: @otome exactly what I needed. Thanks for helping. Forgot about handling more than one result

Answer (score 0):

If the query is selecting just 1 email per row, then should your code look more like this?:

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = strong_crypt($_POST['password'] . $username );
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $taken=false;
 $invalid=false;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   {
       $singleEmail = $row['email'];
       $singleUname = $row['uname'];


   if($singleEmail== $email)
   {
      $message = "That email already exists. You can only have one account per email   
       address.";
       $taken=true;
    }
    else if($singleUname== $username)
   {
       $message = "That username has already been taken. Please choose a different 
        one.";
      $taken=true;
   }
   else if($username == null || $email == null || $password == null || $name == null) 
   {
      $message = "Please fill out all fields to register";
      $invalid=true;
   }

}//end while

if (!$taken && !$invalid){

     mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO login (name, uname, pword, email, lat, lon, it) 
     VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$lat', '$lon', '$it')");
      $message = "goodtogo";

}
```

This would have the whole thing in a loop. checking 1 email at a time.

Otherwise, you could query the database to return ALL emails, put them in an array then compare the inputted email against the array. For example

```
 $allEmails() //assume array populated from db

 if(in_array($email, $allEmails)){ //then it already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your query lines as follow

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `email`='{$email}'"; 
$isEmail = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
if($isEmail>0) $message = "That email already exists. You can only have one account per email address.";
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `uname`='{$name}'";
$isUser = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
if($isUser>0) $message = "That username has already been taken. Please choose a different one.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables `$allEmails` and `$allUnames` contains the values of the last returned entry by database. I would recommend you to change your SQL query to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where `email` = '$email'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where `uname` = '$username'
```

or use an array:

```
$allEmails = array();
$allUnames = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $allEmails[] = $row['email'];
    $allUnames[] = $row['uname'];
}
```

and use the [`in_array()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check wether the entered value is in that array.

Also, your query is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).